# How to execute a query with 2 where statements

Tags: php

what should this code be please:

```
$sql = ("delete * from LogicTempAddress where PostCode=.'"$values['tempPostCode']."' and AddedBy='$AddedBy'");
```

Its PHP and MySQL

Comment: `$sql = ("DELETE * from LogicTempAddress WHERE PostCode='" . $values['tempPostCode'] . "' and AddedBy='" . $AddedBy . "'");`

Comment: what kind of statement.. `delete * from ...  `  ?

Comment: $sql = "DELETE  FROM LogicTempAddress WHERE PostCode='".$values['tempPostCode']."' ANDAddedBy='$AddedBy'";

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
$sql = ("DELETE FROM LogicTempAddress WHERE PostCode='".$values['tempPostCode']."' AND AddedBy='".$AddedBy."'");
```